# Is there a way to center a horizontal LinearLayout

Tags: android

I have a  horizontal LinearLayout with 3 buttons.  Right now the buttons are on the right hand side.  Can I center a LinearLayout so the buttons will be in the center?

Comment: Set the `LinearLayout`'s `gravity` to `center_horizontal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add android:gravity="center_horizontal" to the linear layout which contains buttons as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```